# What kind of JS object is [ foo: 'bar']

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I create a blank array and assign a value:

```js
let a = []
a['foo'] = 'bar'
console.log(a) // [ foo: 'bar'] - not in SO console though
console.log(a[0]) // undefined
console.log(a.length) // 0
console.log(a instanceof Array) // true 
for (let i of a) {} // Doesn't loop but doesn't throw errors like {}
for (let o in a) {
  console.log(o) // foo
}
```

What is this?  An array?, of length 0? what kind of JS thing is this? also it will print to the node console but not recognized by the SO snippet console (run it and look at the web inspector console at same time)

Note that I don't need answers saying to initialize with `{}`. Thats not the point of the question.

Comment: [“Associative arrays in JavaScript are actually treated as Objects”](https://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/01/associative-arrays-in-javascript/)

Comment: Oh fantastic. Learned something new. Every previous mention of assoc array in JS referred to standard objects. Im not sure of its use yet but its an interesting in between arrays and objects. Found this good article too https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/associative.php  - Feel free to add a quick answer.

Comment: Arrays are objects. You should not abuse this fact. Don't add string keys onto arrays, they are meant to be used with numeric keys only. If you do need the equivalent of an associative array, do use an actual `{}` object, or a `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in javascript is an object so is the Array. Array is basically a zero-based keyed object that is iterable so when adding values with string keys into Array you're simply adding keys to that object.

In fact you can create your own object that is iterable just like Array and use it with `for...of` loops. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/gumh6bsy/

> If you run let a = [ foo: 'two', bar: 'one' ] you get an error. So how does the loop in my code get that and print that to the console. Once the loop creates it it seems perfectly manageable. I thought at first it just transformed it into an object but it is an Array instance. – cyberwombat

`let a = [ foo: 'two', bar: 'one' ]` spits an error because square brackets are the syntax for initializing arrays and thus gets validated by javascript engine and does not allow definition of keys in the initialization. Meanwhile key assignment syntax (`a['foo'] = 'two'`) is not in anyway different for both arrays and objects. In fact it is just a syntax for assigning properties to an object. The main takeaway here is that in javascript **array is an object of type Array**. Actually defining array is pretty much the same as defining `let a = { 0: 'one', 1: 'two' }` except that Array (as a type) is recognized as "special" type in javascript that has special syntax for initialization (`let a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]`, gets zero-based numbered keys applied and it is iterable (can be used in `for...of` loops). Of course + all the prototype methods like `find`, `filter`, etc. Having this in mind adding string keyed property to an array is absolutely valid (not recommended) javascript and just because `console.log` applies special formatting when outputting arrays you get `[ foo: 'one', bar: 'two' ]` (with square brackets).

You can even whip-up some very rough implementation of array yourself, like: https://jsfiddle.net/t96ehm1r/ (of course without any syntax sugar for quick initialization and all the prototype methods, etc.)

Comment: I am entering key value pairs not strings. And why doesn't the SO overflow snippet console handle it the same? I assume it has to do with browser JS vs NodeJS and what is this difference.

Comment: Array elements are key-value pairs too, just keys are not strings but numbers. I'm not sure about SO snippet console but maybe it just has some more analysis on the code...

Comment: If you run `let a = [ foo: 'two', bar: 'one' ]` you get an error. So how does the loop in my code get that and print that to the console. Once the loop creates it it seems perfectly manageable. I thought at first it just transformed it into an object but it is an Array instance.